# Alexa: The requested skill did not provide a valid response on LauchRequest

Tags: alexa-skills-kit

I have started Alexa development very recently. Today I have suddenly started getting

which I did not encounter before.

**The lambda function (index.js):**

```
"use strict";

const Alexa = require("ask-sdk-core");
const http = require("http");

exports.handler = async (event, context, callback) => {
  try {
    if (event.request.type === "LaunchRequest") {
      var welcomeMessage = '<speak>Hi</speak>';

      callback(null, buildResponse(welcomeMessage, false));
    }

    else if (event.request.type === "AMAZON.CancelIntent") {
      var msg2 = "<speak>Stopped!</speak>";

      callback(null, buildResponse(msg2, true));
    }
  } catch (e) {
      context.fail("Exception: ${e}");
  }
};

function buildResponse(response, shouldEndSession) {
  return {
    version: "1.0",
    response: {
      outputSpeech: {
        type: "SSML",
        ssml: response
      },
      shouldEndSession: shouldEndSession
    },
    sessionAttributes: {}
  };
}
```

**package.json file:**

```
{
  "name": "third-test-skill",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "...",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "Subrata Sarkar",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "ask-sdk-core": "^2.5.2",
    "ask-sdk-model": "^1.15.1"
  }
}
```

Steps I followed to create the skill:

- Crated a skill from AWS Alexa console
- Created skill
- Added sample utterances
- Selected Lamda as end point Created a function called movieFacts
- Uploaded .zip file containing the following file structure.

> ```
> node_modules
>   |- ask-sdk-core
>   |- ask-sdk-model
>   |- ask-sdk-runtime
> index.js
> package.json
> package.json.lock
> ```

When I say `movie facts`, I am getting the following message:

> The requested skill did not provide a valid response

And this is the JSON output I am receiving:

```
{
    "version": "1.0",
    "session": {
        "new": false,
        "sessionId": "amzn1.echo-api.session.beca8832-50fe-4d17-96a4-30c855b18a4f",
        "application": {
            "applicationId": "amzn1.ask.skill.bdb88b1b-5a4a-4b37-9b63-71e78337bbca"
        },
        "user": {
            "userId": "amzn1.ask.account.AEG2YALM6KQANVKR3YSUWKVN5DCKE66NJKN23SZIKRKZCVTU67E2JBZ5STPFIN325WNGGO5Z73FMVVL5X2SVEM27YEPD5VFNMPVDQSQK5XYW3NXOXSEIK6YPHE5HTZLGLCWW4VVQHLYECL6YBLG4XOTM2HTV5VCCQMPLVCIATFRSNS4DLHJFLY32JHD5N5MAPFBNRVN3YV7B53A"
        }
    },
    "context": {
        "System": {
            "application": {
                "applicationId": "amzn1.ask.skill.bdb88b1b-5a4a-4b37-9b63-71e78337bbca"
            },
            "user": {
                "userId": "amzn1.ask.account.AEG2YALM6KQANVKR3YSUWKVN5DCKE66NJKN23SZIKRKZCVTU67E2JBZ5STPFIN325WNGGO5Z73FMVVL5X2SVEM27YEPD5VFNMPVDQSQK5XYW3NXOXSEIK6YPHE5HTZLGLCWW4VVQHLYECL6YBLG4XOTM2HTV5VCCQMPLVCIATFRSNS4DLHJFLY32JHD5N5MAPFBNRVN3YV7B53A"
            },
            "device": {
                "deviceId": "amzn1.ask.device.AFXLD474IMHMD5V35NT2ZNUD5YLK2LTEJZUMO6DS2MY7ANONMZDZ67C3MU44OBJ6B5N4TPOXIJ64FBEFEOVOB2K4SSYEN3VTRSIHZETNTBNCDYUG6RGFIOKH7S7OBID6CG3WIHB774LNO4CFKWFUXYSNHD5HIAAXCEDKZ3U4EN7QB6EN4RRHQ",
                "supportedInterfaces": {}
            },
            "apiEndpoint": "https://api.amazonalexa.com",
            "apiAccessToken": "eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImtpZCI6IjEifQ.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.UyCg4MXlOe16SlOyJnjAIiHzVpdLkRjd-izoKkUnGqiyZ0L_5eUpg8tKvVrCvTLNMtJS6ElksxgVfuLcNeOIwSbXtYCOXcSLRYbpcpgFI6oeamOZ2Yo-UMDEjzYi75fABuJyUJyZxp-Pieer8PMZO4G9-5zJXCVY2x3M_dmlpX23UBJDpW0DKddvAOzConmwgdaf3v_EWfc2q8BaCQIM950rEUbejOa08_AwE5CsqjNA9sD22QduE5hs09RV4-F-kU1zKvwwyDVDKyOkdFZQFEmCTC11_jI64re9c22e-hYR4leIE5XntNApMgtwaL-tHyjsJzVDVDfZd2q3w6wxYA"
        },
        "Viewport": {
            "experiences": [
                {
                    "arcMinuteWidth": 246,
                    "arcMinuteHeight": 144,
                    "canRotate": false,
                    "canResize": false
                }
            ],
            "shape": "RECTANGLE",
            "pixelWidth": 1024,
            "pixelHeight": 600,
            "dpi": 160,
            "currentPixelWidth": 1024,
            "currentPixelHeight": 600,
            "touch": [
                "SINGLE"
            ],
            "video": {
                "codecs": [
                    "H_264_42",
                    "H_264_41"
                ]
            }
        }
    },
    "request": {
        "type": "SessionEndedRequest",
        "requestId": "amzn1.echo-api.request.c7b1b910-6309-48aa-af35-10ac0a20b5da",
        "timestamp": "2019-05-07T14:55:10Z",
        "locale": "en-US",
        "reason": "ERROR",
        "error": {
            "type": "INVALID_RESPONSE",
            "message": "An exception occurred while dispatching the request to the skill."
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think removing the ***`<speak>`*** and ***`</speak>`*** tags around the welcome message should do. They are by default generated by Alexa, so you don't need to provide them in your response.

Answer (score 0):

What happened in my case (and definitely worth to check) is that I was using Serverless Framework to deploy Lambda and I changed the configuration in the *serverless.yml* but forgot to update the Lambda ARN in the Alexa Endpoint.

Updating the Endpoint to the correct ARN and rebuilding solved the issue.